# What does "filter" mean in Realistic Ray Tracing?

Tags: raytracing

I'm reading the book *Realistic Ray Tracing* and I couldn't understand the box filter code:

```
void boxFilter(Vector2* samples, int num_samples)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++)
    {
        samples[i].x = samples[i].x - 0.5f;
        samples[i].y = samples[i].y - 0.5f;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, "filter" is an array of weights, and sampling is to generate positions to produce rays, filter is to combine the results (so the filter method should return `float[]`, but the function above returns an `Vector2[]`). What does the code mean?

Comment: It seems this function works on the sampling positions not the sampled values of the image. Is there anything more said in the book about the given function?

Comment: Here you can find the source code of the second edition of REALISTIC RAY TRACING by Peter Shirley and R. Keith Morley (AK Peters, 2003) source code: https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/galileo/src/default/ - maybe this helps to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of box filtering is that no matter where on an image plane "pixel" the sample lands, a box filter causes the renderer to act as if it landed in the exact center of that pixel.

I haven't read that particular book, but I'm guessing that in that code fragment, `sample[].x` and `.y` are the `int` (or previously `floor()`ed) locations where the returned ray hits the image plane, in pixel coordinates. Therefore, subtracting `.5` from each puts the sample in the geometric center of each pixel, hence, it's a box filter.

For an in-depth discussion of box filtering (and other filters), see *Physically-Based Rendering*, Chapter 7, "Sampling and Reconstruction".